# Laravel 5.4 - integration testing role middleware fails

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, integration-testing

I'm trying to test some middleware that checks to see if a user has `x` role with Laravel 5.4/PHPUnit. The role functionality works fine in the browser, but I can't seem to get my tests to pass (I get 403's as expected with someone without the required role) with the following code:

```
public function testSuperAdminRoleRoute()
{
    $admin = factory(User::class)->create();
    $adminRole = \HttpOz\Roles\Models\Role::whereSlug('super.admin')->first();

    $admin->detachAllRoles();
    $admin->attachRole($adminRole);

    $response = $this->actingAs($admin)
                     ->get('/super-admin-only')
                     ->assertStatus(200);
}
```

When I `dd($admin->roles)` I do indeed see the correct role, but I think I'm missing something maybe a limitation within Laravel/PHPUnit. I have previously tested this sort of functionality in my acceptance tests and had it work.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to the package author ([httoz](https://github.com/httpoz/roles/issues/44)), we believe it's due to a limitation of Laravel's `be()` or `actingAs()` methods. We're not really 100% sure as to why, but I believe sessions come into play, and PHPUnit uses an array as session storage, so I'm pushed towards that.

I tried to use `$this->disableMiddleware()`, but because I use the `$error` bag in my views (and that is set via middleware), my tests 500 because `$errors` isn't defined.

However, reading this proposed change in Laravel 5.5: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18673

I copied the code from that push:

```
public function withoutMiddleware($middleware = null)
{
    if (is_null($middleware)) {
        $this->app->instance('middleware.disable', true);
        return $this;
    }
    $nullMiddleware = new class {
        public function handle($request, $next)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
    };
    foreach ((array) $middleware as $abstract) {
        $this->app->instance($abstract, $nullMiddleware);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

and set updated my `$this->withoutMiddleware()` calls to this:

```
$this->withoutMiddleware([
    \HttpOz\Roles\Middleware\VerifyRole::class, 
    \HttpOz\Roles\Middleware\VerifyGroup::class
]);
```

and I get green again!